# Retrieve and echo random item from database, and continue to echo for five seconds

Tags: php, mysql

The following program does just this!

```
<?php
/************************************
AIM: To retrieve and echo a random item from a database, and continue to echo the same item whenever and whereever the page is reloaded, for five seconds. After the five seconds is up, the program must echo another random item, and contine ad infinitum.
CONDITIONS: The program cannot echo two results in a row. (In effect the same result for ten seconds).
*************************************/
// Get ready to seed a random value from future 'rand()' function. Seed for 5 seconds.
srand(floor(time() / (5)));

// Retreieve all rows from table 'dogs'.
$result1 = $mysqli->query = new mysqli("SELECT * FROM dogs", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

// See how many rows are in 'dogs'.
mysqli_result::$num_rows;

// Generate a random value between 1 and the number of rows in 'dogs'.
echo $random = rand(1,$num_rows) . '<br>';

// Find the current date as a unix timestamp.
echo $currentdate = time() . '<br>';

// Find the time ten seconds ago.
echo $datetensecondsago = $currentdate - 10;
echo '<br>';

?>
```

However, I have no idea on how to get it to not echo the same random database item twice in a row!

Database schematics is as follows:

```
Table Name = dogs
id  |  name  |  lastused
------------------------
1   |  Rover |  1362960167
2   |  Chip  |  1362960123
3   |  Rex   |  1362960178
```

I think the answer lies in a mysql query such as

```
SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE dateused<$datetensecondsago LIMIT 1
```

and then updating the timeused of a used item but I can't quite work it out!

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the random row in a session variable (which is accessible even if you reload the page (and the session is not expired)).

```
 session_start();
 // store session data
 $_SESSION['my_variable'] = 'something';
```

Then you can check if an element has been already echoed or (**better**) you can exclude it with a WHERE clause in your SQL like:
`SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id <> LAST_ID` (width LAST_ID = id of the last echoed element).

---

You can use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` to retrieve the number of rows in a mysql table.

---

There's a simpler method to get a random row from a table:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

There's also similar but faster methods (if interested just google *mysql random*)

---

Have you considered using javascript or even AJAX?
With javascript there's no need for page reload to change its content.